# Using SQLite in electron new window makes program halt

Tags: node.js, sqlite, electron

I'm using electron 28.1.4, SQLite3 4.18.2.
I wanted to create database using SQLite in electron when user click 'create' button in popup window.

So I first made function which create sqlite database using sqlite3 library in main and exposed it using contextBridge.

In renderer side, I first create new route for the page '/project/create' and added button that can call sqlite function using button. Finally, called `window.open(URL)` to open child window showing '/project/create' page.

I clicked 'Create' button in child window but entire page (including primary window) went blank and DevTools was disconnected from the page. Error message shown in electron is

> [1] /Users/yeji/dev/icarus/icarus-app/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Frameworks/Electron Helper (Renderer).app/Contents/MacOS/Electron Helper (Renderer)[1562]: ../../third_party/electron_node/src/api/callback.cc:74:node::InternalCallbackScope::InternalCallbackScope(Environment *, Local, const async_context &, int): Assertion `(Environment::GetCurrent(isolate)) == (env)' failed.

I just changed primary window to load '/project/create' instead of '/' to test my function in primary instead of child and everything worked okay. But I want it to be done in child window. What is the problem and how can I solve it? Thank you advance!

**Creating window (renderer)**

```
window.open('http://localhost:3000/project/create', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600,title="Create project"');
```

**Createing database (main)**

```
function createProject(path: string): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise((
    resolve: (path: string) => void,
    reject: (err: any) => void
  ) => {
    const db: Database = new Database(path, (err: Error | null) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
    initDatabase(db);
    cleanupDatabase(db);
    resolve(path);
  });
}
```

**Exposing function to renderer (main)**

```
const coreProjectContext = {
  createProject: createProject
}

export {
  coreProjectContext,
  registerCoreProjectIpc
}
```

**Calling function (renderer)**

```
function create() {
  coreProject.createProject(path)
    .then(() => {
      coreWindow.closeCurrentWindow();
    })
    .catch((err: Error) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
}
```

**Router in react (renderer)**

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={'/'} element={<MainFrame />}/>
        <Route path={'/project/create'} element={<CreateProject />}/>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```